# AFNetworking POST request not working in 3G

Tags: ios, objective-c, http, ios7, afnetworking-2

I am using the AFNetworking lib version 2.2.2 and I want to upload an image to my server using a POST request. In WiFi everything is working like a charm. The server returns a JSON response and also HTTP 200 response code, so it's no server side issue.

If I use the POST request in 3G I always get a "Timed out" exception and I don't know why.

This is my code

```
NSMutableDictionary * params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
if(![self isTextEmpty]) {
    [params setValue:textView.text forKey:@"t"];
}

[httpOperationManager POST:@"http://......." parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    if(imageData != nil) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"p" fileName:@"filename" mimeType:@"image/jpg"];
    }
} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Done!!!");

    [hud hide:YES];

    [self.delegate updateData];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error sending post!" message:@"Error" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];

    [hud hide:YES];
}];
```

As you can see, the code is quite simple. I also used the variant using the process block. With the progress block I see that the file is uploaded completely but the method always returns with a "Timed out" exception.

The files I want to upload are really small, currently I am testing with 200kb files, but I also tested smaller ones without success.

I hope you can help me!
Thx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

Adding data to the dictionary to be sent.

```
 [registerInputDict setValue:self.fileIdString
                         forKey:@"profileImageId"];
```

Sending the dictionay to AFNetwork Classes.

```
[super postRequestDataWithLoginURL:@"api/user.json" andRequestName:USER_REGISTER andPostData:userDict];


- (AFHTTPRequestOperation *)postRequestDataWithLoginURL:(NSString *)url andRequestName:(NSString *)requestName
                                        andPostData:(NSDictionary*)postData {
[self showProgressIndicator];

AFHTTPClient *afHTTPClient = [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:BASEURL];

[afHTTPClient setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];


DebugLog(@"Current Language %@ ",[UserDefaultUtils retriveObjectForKey:LANGUAGE]);
if ([UserDefaultUtils retriveObjectForKey:LANGUAGE]) {

    [afHTTPClient setDefaultHeader:@"x-language-code" value:[UserDefaultUtils retriveObjectForKey:LANGUAGE]];

}
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [afHTTPClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:url parameters:postData];


AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [afHTTPClient HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {


    [self successWithRequest:operation withRespose:responseObject withRequestName:requestName];

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    [self failedWithRequest:operation witherror:error withRequestName:requestName];

}];

[afHTTPClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];

return operation;
}
```

The Success and Failure response methods.

```
- (void)failedWithRequest:(AFHTTPRequestOperation *)operation witherror:(NSError *)error withRequestName:(NSString *)requestName {

id  jsonObject = [operation.responseString objectFromJSONString];

DebugLog(@"registration failed:%@",[error description]);

if ([requestName isEqualToString:UPLOAD_PHOTO]) {

    if  ([self.loginProxyDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(imageUploadFailed:)]) {

        [self.loginProxyDelegate imageUploadFailed:[jsonObject objectForKey:@"messages"]];
    }

}

}


- (void)successWithRequest:(AFHTTPRequestOperation *)operation withRespose:(id)responseObject withRequestName:(NSString *)requestName {

id  jsonObject = [operation.responseString objectFromJSONString];

if ([requestName isEqualToString:UPLOAD_PHOTO]) {

    [self handleResponseForGetUploadPhoto:jsonObject];

}

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I'll give it a try, but I think I already tried it your way - with the same result. But I'll try your code. Did you use your code in iOS6 or iOS7? I've read somewhere, Apple kind of messed up the network code in iOS7, that's why there are so many problems...

Comment: Sorry, I just wanted to try your code but it looks like you are using AFNetworking 1.0 and I am using AFNetworking 2.2.2.. the API is incompatible.